# How to print below output in TCL

Tags: tcl

How to print the below output in for loop in TCL

puts Result1=$result1

puts Result2=$result2

puts Result3=$result3

Since $result2 is a value i need it exactly like $result2 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach n {1 2 3} {
    puts [format {puts Result%d=$result%d} $n $n]
    # or
    puts "puts Result$n=\$result$n"
}
```

---

You need to remember that when Tcl parses a command, it only performs a single round of substitutions (in the order [given here](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm))

When you write `puts "Result $i is $result$i"` when `i` is 1, Tcl will **not** first substitute $i to form `$result1`. It will see `result` as a separate variable:

```
set result1 foo
set result2 bar
set result3 baz
foreach n {1 2 3} {
    puts "Result $n is $result$n"
}
```

```
can't read "result": no such variable
```

If you want to use variable names like that, you first have to form the proper variable name, and then get the value. For this you use the `set` command with a single argument:

```
foreach n {1 2 3} {
    puts "Result $n is [set result$n]"
}
```

```
Result 1 is foo
Result 2 is bar
Result 3 is baz
```

However it is easier to work with arrays than it is to use "dynamic" variable names like that. Choose one of these instead:

```
# an associative array
set result(1) foo
set result(2) bar
set result(3) baz
foreach n {1 2 3} {
    puts "Result $n is $result($n)"
}

# or a dictionary
unset result
set result [dict create 1 foo 2 bar 3 baz]
foreach n {1 2 3} {
    puts "Result $n is [dict get $result $n]"
}
```

Associative arrays are simple to use, but they're a bit harder to pass around to procedured. Dictionaries are first-class objects

Comment: Thanks a lot jackman for your reply                                                                                          but i want the content of $result1,2,3 which works with below code                                                                                                                        for { set i 1 } { $i <= 10 } { incr i } {
    puts "Result$i=[expr \$result$i]" 
}
+>+>+>                                                                                      Result1=0
Result2=0
Result3=0
Anyways thanks a lot for the initial code.

Comment: I have few doubts can you pls help to clarify my doubt ,             previously i tried below code                                                                  for { set i 1 } { $i <= 10 } { incr i } {
puts "Result$i= $result$i"
}                                                                                                         which did not work. So what is the difference between /$result$i and  $result$i ?

Comment: Thanks a lot jackman for the detailed explanation. That helped me a lot.